# How to retrieve session id of active user

Tags: windows, session, batch-file

Suppose that I'm currently running in session 0 (as a windows service) .. i want to find which user is now ACTIVE! and then retrieve that "sessionID", what can i do using WINDOWS BATCH COMMAND ?

Comment: What happens if your code is running on a Windows (terminal) server where multiple users may be logged in and active?

Comment: Have you tried `qwinsta`?

Comment: @selbie: suppose that there is exactly only one user which is now active and running my code.. how to retrieve that user sessionID and also user's computername :) please suggest..

Answer (score 0):

Replace `remotehost` with your IP:

```
qwinsta /server remotehost
```